# Switch between silverlight and HTML5

Tags: c#, javascript, html, silverlight

I have a Silverlight application and we are currently transitioning to HTML5.

I have finished one page and we would like to be able to switch between them but there is a problem. The page I have worked on is the page the user sees first when they log in. We would like the Html page to load and the Silverlight app to be hidden.

This is how the index page now looks like:

```
@using DTO
@model Models.QMForm
@{
    ViewBag.Title = ".:: QM";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/MainLayout.cshtml";
 }

 @section menu
 {
    @if (this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        if (@Model is Manager)
        {
            <li id="home" class="active">
            <a href="#" id="menu_dashboard" onclick="navigateTo
               ('home');">@Model.menuDashboard</a></li>
        }

        <li id="performancecenter">
        <a href="#" id="menu_performance" onclick="navigateTo 
           'performancecenter');">@Model.menuPerformance</a></li>

        if (@Model is Manager || @Model is ApplicationAdministrator)
        {
            <li id="designcenter">
            <a href="#" id="menu_design" onclick="navigateTo      
               ('designcenter');">@Model.menuDesign</a></li>
        }   
    }
}

<div id="silverlightControlHost" style="padding: 0; margin: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
     <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" id="silverlight_control" 
        style="width: 100%; border: 0px; border-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0;">
    <param name="source" value="~/ClientBin/Coach.UI.QM.xap" />
    <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
    <param name="background" value="white" />
    <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="5.1.20513.0" />
    <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
    <param name="Windowless" value="true" />
    <param name="splashscreensource" value="~/SplashScreen.xaml" />
    <param name="onSourceDownloadProgressChanged" value="onSourceDownloadProgressChanged" />
    <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=5.1.20513.0" style="text-decoration:none">
        <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
    </a>
    </object>
</div>
```

The `navigateTo(view)` javascript function looks like this

```
function navigateTo(navName) {
    var control = document.getElementById("silverlight_control");
    if (control && control.Content && control.Content.MainPage) {
        control.Content.MainPage.onNavClicked(navName);
        setMenu(navName);
    }
}
```

The problem here is that we need to have Silverlight running when the app loads because the we need it to navigate later from the first (home) screen to the rest.

I have first tried to add the `div` on top of the Silverlight host and then play around with `.show()` and `.hide()` but if I don't set the Silverlight control to be hidden I will have a huge scrollbar and my new HTML stuff above the Silverlight div.

If the Silverlight div is hidden at the beginning then it doesn't load and I can't navigate away from the home screen.

Any ideas how I can switch between them in a easy way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the css hide trick on the silverlight div instead of setting display:none?

```
.hide {
   position: absolute !important;
   top: -9999px !important;
   left: -9999px !important;
}
```

http://css-tricks.com/places-its-tempting-to-use-display-none-but-dont/

Comment: Nice stuff! Will try this one out!